# Using JLabel for a background image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

When I run the code it just opens an empty window
I also important whatever is necessary

relevant parts of the code:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    private JLabel background; 
....  
public Game(){
background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/graphics/board.gif"));
...
this.add(background);
this.setSize(800,600);
this.setVisible(true);...
```

I tried adding the JLabel to a JPanel and then add it to the frame but it still shows nothing in the window

Comment: I think you are using the wrong constructor for `JLabel` (assuming you don't want to show the *text* "/graphics/board.gif").

Answer (score 2):

Originally the code was:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel("/graphics/board.gif");
```

This would not set the image at the path described, Suggest that the following method is used (this could be simplified to just use a different JLabel constructor but steps shown for clarity)

Create and load the image and then set the icon for the Label As follows

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/graphics/board.gif"); 
JLabel background = new JLabel();
background.setIcon(icon);
```

[Link to ImageIcon Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html)

Comment: Nope it shouldn't but thats not what original post was. It was `new JLabel("/graphics/board.gif");`

Answer (score 0):

It is important to set in the layout the order in which the elements are displayed , maybe you have something that is displayed over the label..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a directory structure something like:

```
-c:\java  
  - source (for source and class files)  
    - graphic (for your images)
```

```
background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/graphics/board.gif"));
```

Don't specify the leading "/" in the file name. That tells Java to look at the root of the C drive, not at the directory where your class is executing from.

Also, don't use:

```
this.setSize(800,600);
```

The image does not stretch to fill the size of the frame. Intead you should be using:

```
this.pack();
```

so the frame will be the size of the image.